# Unexplained undefined value on return

Tags: javascript

I've got an issue with an undefined value in below code that neither me nor any of my collegues can explain:

```
function reverseFactorial(num) {
  function reverse(altNum, fac){
  console.log(altNum + ', ' + fac);
    if ((altNum / fac) === 1)
            {  
            console.log(fac.toString() + '!');
       return fac.toString() + '!'; 
            }

       else {
       reverse(altNum / fac, fac + 1);
       }
  }
  var ret = reverse(num, 1);
  console.log(ret);
  return ret;
}
```

An example input could be: `reverseFactorial(120)`.

The logs would then show this:

> 120, 1
>
> 120, 2
>
> 60, 3
>
> 20, 4
>
> 5, 5
>
> 5!
>
> undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reverse` function doesn't always return a value: the `else {` case has no return statement.

You probably mean to `return reverse(altNum / fac, fac + 1);` in the `else` block.